# Не работает запрос mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает этот запрос. В `phpmyadmin` сам запрос дает результат, таблица обновляется, но когда я запускаю `php-скрипт` работать не хочет. **Хотя и ошибок вроде нету. Я думаю, этот из-за скобок. Или что?**

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
    $text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
    $author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));

    mysql_query("   UPDATE users SET title=$title, text='$text', author='$author' 
                    WHERE id='$id' ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка тут `title=$title,` кавычек нет.
А так очень не хорошо пишите, используйте `PDO`а то можно так таких дел натворить,

```
// Подключение
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
$strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
$author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));

$sql = "UPDATE users SET title='$title', text='$text', author='$author' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Обновилось
printf("Обновилось записей: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Comment: Серавно не работает...

Comment: @Cactus сделайте как тут [mysql-query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)  
`mysql_error()`  
что-бы просмотреть ошибки

Comment: нету ошибок.. даже не знаю, что делать

Comment: @Cactus не буквально, описание измените, укажите весь код, так где идет подключение  
и ваш листинг поправьте примерно так

`$sql = "UPDATE users SET title='$title', text='$text', author='$author' 
                    WHERE id='$id'"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: @Cactus посмотрите, что-то в этом роде должно быть